# Appscan putting backslash in between CSS property names OR property value and flagged it as Cross site Scripting issue

Tags: css, regex

We ran Appscan recently on our PHP project. The scan report says `""style =font-family:expression(alert(3614))!` is an issue since if I pass this string as the value in URL, then I will get an alert.
So I wrote a regex to resolve the issue and the regex is: `/[\s]*\bstyle[\s]*=[\s]*[^:]*:[\s]*expression\b/i`

and `/[\s]*\bstyle[\s]*=[\s]*[^=]*=[\s]*expression\b/i` to address some more issues.

Now I ran scan one more time to check whether my code is working fine or not and this time the appscan reported a similar issue but embedding a backslash in between the characters and the issue is:
`""style =font-family:expres\sion(alert(3614))!`

Please note that backslash inserted in between 's' in expression string.

I am having some doubts please clarify.

```
#myDiv {
    background-color: red;
    height: expression(document.body.offsetHeight);
}
```

is same as

```
#myDiv {
    back\g\r\o\u\nd-color: red;
    height: e\x\p\res\s\i\on(document.body.offsetHeight);
}
```

except backslash in front of 'e' OR 'b' OR 'a' OR 'c'

above CSS code produce same output with and without backslashes. Can someone explain what is the issue and how I can resolve this issue so that Appscan is happy

Comment: Can anybody answer to my question?

Comment: Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

AppScan tests many different variants (payloads) for what could be reported as the same issue.  What I believe you are seeing here is that one of those variants was not filtered using the regexp you had defined.  Resulting in the positive finding.